# How to keep params with react-router v4?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, universal, i18next

I have a React/Redux Universal application and I have recently added [i18next](https://www.i18next.com/) to add internalization to my website.

In my react-router config, I have edited my routes:

```
const routes = [
  {
    component: App,
    routes: [
      { path: '/:lng(fr|en)?/', exact: true, component: Home },
      { path: '/:lng?/about', component: About },
      …
      { component: NotFound }
    ]
  }
];
```

Everything works well, but I don't know how to keep the `lng` paramaters between my pages. Indeed, when I use `<Link to="/about" >`, I logically lost my params.

So, how to keep this parameter?

Thanks

Comment: In which component `<Link to="/about" >` used?

Comment: In my containers, I use them to navigate between my pages. [Link](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/api/Link.md)

Comment: why you can not do like this `<Link to=`/about/${this.props.match.params.lng}` `

Comment: Of course I can, but I would like something more flexible.

Comment: Could you please share container part as well

Comment: The website is based on this repo: https://github.com/bertho-zero/react-redux-universal-hot-example/blob/master/src/containers/Home/Home.js